# Enableeventvalidation in web user control

Tags: validation, events, user-controls

I have a web user control containing a repeater. The repeater contains three buttons. On button click it gives the following error :

`Invalid postback or callback argument.`

Event validation is enabled using `<pages enableEventValidation="true"/>` in configuration or `<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %>` in a page.

For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the `ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation` method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Since user control does  not have page directive, so I changed the `enableEventValidation` to false in `web.config`, but it restricted the itemcommand event of the repeater.

Can someone guide me, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old question, but recently struggled with the same problem.

The solution is to put code that bounds data to your repeater inside of code that will work if PostBack not happened for the page:

```
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            rptTeam.DataSource = lstUSTU;
            rptTeam.DataBind();
        }
```

Hope that helps.